# Am I doing this right? (LED's to music)

Tags: led, audio, theory

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSqWbQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have been charged with designing and making a circuit that makes LEDs brighten or dim to an audio source. At the time I thought I had a much greater understanding about electricity than I actually did. The questions and answers on this exchange have been instrumental in my coming to understand how it all really works, alongside the many useful and helpful links that people have posted in their answers.

After much searching, reading and experimenting, I feel I understand enough to ask a question or two of my own. Above is the schematic for my working circuit. I'm still trying to fine tune it and understand what my changes are doing, but that will have to wait until my parts can arrive in the mail.

In short, I have two questions about my design and the theory behind it.

First: How do I apply Kirchhoff's law of voltage to my circuit? Do I need to worry about Kirchhoff's law in my circuit? I understand that the total voltage drop across the circuit is supposed to reach 0 (9 volts in, 9 volts consumed), but I don't quite understand where the LED's fit into the equation. Obviously they're going to be applied as resistance, but there is no resistance rating on the packaging they came in. They're rated for 3V at .02A. If you plug those numbers into Ohm's law you get 150 Ohms of resistance, but if the LED had that much resistance I wouldn't need to put a resistor in front of it to keep it from having a much higher amperage and building up heat. Without knowing what resistance the LED's have (or how they consume voltage without that resistance) I'm left unsure of how to apply the law.

Second: Am I missing anything? I'm still new to the theory of all this and learning more every day, but my circuit 'works' to my eyes. I do understand that there could be quite a few things going wrong where I can't visually observe them, which is why I'm reaching out to the community. I've seen circuits that use capacitors somewhere between the LEDs and the audio signal. I understand this has to do with analog wave forms, but my understanding stops about there. I also lack the tools to test and see if the wave form coming out of my audio source (my phone) is an actual analog wave or a digital wave.

If you see something else wrong with my circuit, please feel free to point it out and explain or link me to a page that explains it (or both, I like both). Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Since my knowledge of this subject is entirely self tought (my formal learning is all on the software side of things!), "here, go read this" is a perfectly acceptable reply!

Comment: Yuk.  Please fix your schematic to be more logically layed out.  Put high voltages at top, low voltages at bottom, logical flow left to right, etc.  Your schematic as it is now it just too annoying to look at.  We shouldn't have to decypher the schematic to see the circuit.

Comment: What voltage range you expect the "audio source" will get?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly I'd re-arrange your diagram to make more logical sense: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fROnFn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've placed the transistor at the 0V end of the power rail so it's easier to interface an audio signal to it. I've also put a resistor in series with the base to limit the base current to avoid damage. I've also made the supply 12V as I'm sure you intend it to be given the your LED current limiter is 450 ohms and you intend the LED current to be 20 mA.

The LEDs have a forward voltage across them of 3V at 20mA and you'd probably find that if you lowered the voltage to (say) 2.5v, the current would be less than 5mA - LEDs have a non-linear characteristic making them non-ideal candidates for Kirchoff!!

It's normal practise to look at the LED characteristic in the data sheet and estimate what the forward volts are for the current at which you want to run the device. This you have done and the 450 ohm at 20mA will drop 3V therefore the power supply I assume you meant to show is 12V dc.

I would also consider things that can be done to filter the audio signal before it feeds the transistor. For a start I'd probably put a reverse diode across the base-emitter to prevent negative base-emitter voltages damaging the transistor. I might also consider low pass filtering the signal so that the music only lit the LEDs when the beats triggered it. Usually a kick drum will produce the largest amplitude signal and I'd try and pick this out to trigger the LEDs.

Comment: It's a little early for me to say anything about filtering the audio, but it is on my to-do list of things to learn and apply. Unfortunately my input voltage is fixed (a single 9V battery), so it would be easier to simply remove one of the LEDs in the chain. How did you come to the conclusion that the resistor dissipates 3 volts? I thought that was what Kirchhoff's law was meant to calculate, but you've said that LED's aren't suited for that.

Comment: 3v and 20mA, by ohms law makes a resistor of  150 ohms. Oops mistakes have conspired against me LOL